# Animation with Physics (Cloth | Collision)

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation, collision

### Problem

How can I make the fabric stop exactly where the tube thickens and prevent it from continuing its free fall to infinity and beyond

### Example

I want the fabric to stop exactly when it reaches this area
[image: attachment point]

### Result of the animation with physics

[image]

## what should be

[image: expectation]

### Second Try

[image: Second try settings]
[image: settings]

Comment: How about an invisible collar that's wider, combined with an invisible floor ?  (rigid body->passive)  Either that or allowing it to fall until you stop it by keyframing the 'Dynamic' box off.  Perhaps a combination of both physics and animation from there?  You can always 'freeze' the cloth when it reaches the shape you're seeking, duplicate it even and swap over to that. All suggestions from someone who hasn't tried this I know, but it costs nought to try. ;)

Comment: I ignore the subject hahaha, I have dedicated more to the programming part in blender, that to animate, I'm good at modeling, programming some things that I implement in 279, but they are in C ++ I do not use piton, and I liked that part so I left I'm interested in animation, but now I also want to grow on that side, and be able to valance my BGE project

Comment: how would you do it? give me an example

Comment: I've not used soft bodies except for experimentation, but I do a lot of combination physics and animation, and have 'tripped over' some good solutions that actually eliminate the thorns that prickle us in Blender, ha ha.  I'd be happy to answer any specific questions in that area.

Comment: add an image but observe, I have a vague idea of what to do, but I do not know how to set the settings correctly so that this works well

Comment: I'm in the middle of tax returns here and am having a short break to clear my mind with Blender.  Will have a play around with your idea.  I like the render you've produced BTW.  In the meantime you could try the 'Invisible floor, and 'freezing' suggestion.  Work from there.  I imagine there are people here who could work on a driver or scripting solution also.

Comment: check the last images in the post

Comment: Soft cloth dynamics and settings are not something I've done a lot with of late so I can't comment on those without trying them myself.  You've caught my curiosity though and I dare say I'll be duplicating what you've got there.  I've got this question url stored so I'll be watching and you never know, might come up with something.  Others would be more qualified and helpful I'm sure.

Comment: So if you liked the question, vote up to be seen by more people and not be forgotten

Comment: Have done - it was the rendered animation I thought was good.

Comment: there must be a form of restriction of vertices to avoid stretching the mesh in the center

Comment: Moving to chat?  Yes thanks.  I was wondering if users could chat between themselves, much like email.

Comment: I played with cloth physics last night for some hours and am about to duplicate your shaft and collar, see what happens.  This thread (no pun intended) will be moved to a chat board for us, so we can continue on in there. (if we can find it.  :)  )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96138/discussion-between-blender-blackened-and-edgel3d).

Answer (score 1):

Cloth -  You've already found the settings that prevent the cloth falling through the wider section of the cylinder.  Your second query, re: stretching at the cloth's aperture...

Edit 17th July 2019 -

No stretch -  An alternative solution - (See below for the other)

Scripting might be able to circumvent Blender's physics from stretching the cloth's aperture but to do it from the desktop, it appears only a slight-of-hand workaround will avoid this.

[image]

The physics engine starts expanding the hole when it approaches the upper end of the pipe, so why not decrease the diameter of that pipe.  The hole will still expand but to a lesser degree.

Next we duplicate the pipe and strip that of all physics and animation so it's only scenery and therefore incapable of influencing the cloth.  That's then expanded in the X & Y axis' so it's the same height but fatter.

The original pipe (with physics) is made invisible but will still be seen by the physics engine and affect the cloth as before.

The end result is that the cloth will appear to be a snug fit at all times.

-===============-

Info - The cloth's wriggling is stopped by virtue of a swap with a duplicate of itself that's frozen at the switch-over frame, (the physics modifier applied).   Not recommended for beginners.  Post production in the VSE would be an easier way to achieve this.

-====================-

The earlier solution/suggestion -

[image]

It appears that inserting a hole in the cloth gives rise to unavoidable stretching at the aperture as it approaches the upper end of the cylinder.

A convincing workaround would be to add a mesh (non-cloth) ring or collar with the same material as the cloth.  That's then animated so it follows the cloth's descent.

[image]

Rather than add a new ring, the original cloth was duplicated and cleared of physics and animation at frame 1.

The outer faces are cut away, leaving the original material in what's left.  This should make it easier to match up should the cloth be textured.

Comment: yea, Yes, I had already thought about that and I already had notion about the stretching of the central ring of the fabric, but I do not understand what you say about the ring I had the basic idea but it is not clear to me, there must be another way where just being a restriction to the vertices of that central ring, and that's what I look for because it's to apply to another simulation of more complex fiches and does not contemplate that addition, it's not bad in fact it's very good, just that it looks more like a patch, you could put captures of the process?

Comment: I also notice that it has a bounce and there should be no rebound, I'm 80% sure that is due to that rigid ring that generates a malicious effect secondary to the simulation, although lack of physical influence on the behavior of the fabric which causes behave like a ball and a little bounce, I have never seen a fabric bounce, even containing elastin! you can see my point

Comment: Observe the ring video - there's no bounce.  That's the physics engine doing that to the original cloth and will be due to my settings, they're obviously not tweaked enough.  If you can determine which is the 'patch' and which is the ring from a gif file, you've got better eyes than mine!  They're using the same material.  It was a suggested workaround without knowledge of your ultimate goal. -  I'll delete it if you wish.

Comment: no, please, it's very good, just that I've practicad doing this, I already know most of the results, maybe that's why I beat you when I detect something that has already happened to me and I see it, rather what you need to put is the process how to do it so that someone new to you can serve, for example, how you related to what you are doing or what parent and what child

Comment: just add the steps to follow and if you can also images to be complete, you and I assume to see the question and the images and what to do but a novice or someone without experience, you will not know how to do it, you just lack that and I rated it accepted

Comment: physics simulations scale does matter. Blender is designed to work with real world sizes and real world weights. When using cycles, lights work also in real world scale, both in terms of intensity and falloff.

Comment: Hi again, not sure what you're trying to say in your last, re: the physics engine.  As for the cloth wanting to wriggle, this is stoppable when you apply the physics at the same frame you do the switch.

It's a strict procedure that has to be carried out in a certain order and is really a different subject to your current question. You appear to be familiar with this trick anyway. To explain this for a novice would require significant time to put an answer together as each and every step would have to be explained.  With tax returns taking my time at the mo, perhaps you'd like to do that. :)

Comment: Just to clarify, re: physics.  The collar is just animated scenery,   It has no physics or parentage and consequently, the physics engine isn't aware it's there and certainly won't react to it.  Hope that addresses your last comment.

Comment: it does not work for me, it's not a simulation of physics anymore, it's an animation simulating physics, and that's not what I intend, a bad patch, like putting a post-it on your pants so you do not see the hole

Comment: Sad, but true...

Comment: this is a suggestion, do the experiment with real materials, use PVC pipes and the fabric you use is LYCRA
1 meter fall
and 2 meters of fabric

tube that guides the fall is 2.5 inches
the one that stops the fabric a cylindrical tank for common plastic water

Comment: We should be done with this one thanks - I know I'm out of ideas.

Comment: 1 give you + 1 for your hard work my friend

Comment: Thanks @Blender Blackened   Good luck with your project.