# Cloth simulation bouces around when falling - does not settle

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

Thanks in advance! Version 2.82.6

I am trying to drop a bedspread on top of a bed.  When I run the cloth sim, the bedspreads falls just a little then bounces/dances around and never reaches the mattress, or almost reaches the mattress and wiggles, never really 'grounding out'.  I tried the most basic example with the default cube (collision) and a plane (cloth) and it worked great, the cloth simply landed on the cube and steeled - I tried identical settings and it's still not working as desired.  I've also reviewed the collision object settings - What am I missing?
Bedspread having a dance 
[image: Bedspread having a dance]

Cube looks nice
[image]

Comment: Your settling problem will be a matter of settings and some skullduggery to force it onto the bed. I managed to stop the dancing by 'applying' the physics modifier at the frame I wanted it to settle, saving that as a separate Blend file and importing that cloth into the original project.  At the exact frame it was applied the two are switched visually. (The eye and camera icons in the Outliner)  See here, the top video and explanation further below under "Info".

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145112/animation-with-physics-cloth-collision/145251#145251

Answer (score -1):

Scale up the size of the mattress and the bed sheets, run the simulation and then scale them down again.