# Why is my cloth simulation bouncing?

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

[Video of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTlV.jpg)
Everything is shown in video.
I put quality steps on pretty high value, but problem is still present.

I can upload Blender file if it's going help.

I have cloth hanging from top vertices and plane that moves from underneath the cloth, few units up and slightly makes curtain wrinkled at the bottom, as most of theatrical curtains/drapes are. It looks nice but because its supposed to be animatedm i have problem with bottom of curtain constantly twitching and bouncing.

Cloth has subdivison before and after the cloth modifier. Plane that "pushes" curtain from bottom has standard collision enabled.

So basically my problem is cloth that never really settles. It moves and wtiches a little bit but it's still enough to make it wierd and very unrealistic.

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Here, I elaborated it a bit more.

Comment: The cloth's wriggling can be stopped by virtue of a swap with a duplicate of itself that's frozen at the switch-over frame, (the physics modifier applied). Not recommended for beginners. Post production in the VSE would be an easier way to achieve this.  See the result and method here (1st video)  -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145112/animation-with-physics-cloth-collision/145251#145251